# How can I extract all the instances of a regular expression pattern in PySpark dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `StringType()` column in a PySpark dataframe. I want to extract all the instances of a regexp pattern from that string and put them into a new column of `ArrayType(StringType())`

Suppose the regexp pattern is `[a-z]\*([0-9]\*)`

```
Input df:
+-----------+
|stringValue|
+-----------+
|a1234bc123 |
|av1tb12h18 |
|abcd       | 
+-----------+

Output df:
+-----------+-------------------+
|stringValue|output             |
+-----------+-------------------+
|a1234bc123 |['1234', '123']    |
|av1tb12h18 |['1', '12', '18']  |
|abcd       |[]                 |
+-----------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In **Spark 3.1+** [`regexp_extract_all`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#regexp_extract_all) is available.

> **`regexp_extract_all(str, regexp[, idx])`** - Extract all strings in the `str` that match the `regexp` expression and corresponding to the regex group index.

```
df = df.withColumn('output', F.expr(r"regexp_extract_all(stringValue, '[a-z]*(\\d+)', 1)"))

df.show()
#+-----------+-----------+
#|stringValue|     output|
#+-----------+-----------+
#| a1234bc123|[1234, 123]|
#| av1tb12h18|[1, 12, 18]|
#|       abcd|         []|
#+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use the `split` and `array_remove` from `functions` in spark:

1. create the test DataFrame

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([("a1234bc123",), ("av1tb12h18",), ("abcd",)],["stringValue"])
df.show()
```

The original DataFrame:

```
+-----------+
|stringValue|
+-----------+
| a1234bc123|
| av1tb12h18|
|       abcd|
+-----------+
```

2. Use `split` to separate the strings into numbers only

```
df = df.withColumn("mid", F.split('stringValue', r'[a-zA-Z]'))
df.show()
```

The output:

```
+-----------+-----------------+
|stringValue|              mid|
+-----------+-----------------+
| a1234bc123|  [, 1234, , 123]|
| av1tb12h18|[, , 1, , 12, 18]|
|       abcd|       [, , , , ]|
+-----------+-----------------+
```

3. Finally, use `array_remove` to remove non-number elements

```
df = df.withColumn("output", F.array_remove('mid', ''))
df.show()
```

The final output:

```
+-----------+-----------------+-----------+
|stringValue|              mid|     output|
+-----------+-----------------+-----------+
| a1234bc123|  [, 1234, , 123]|[1234, 123]|
| av1tb12h18|[, , 1, , 12, 18]|[1, 12, 18]|
|       abcd|       [, , , , ]|         []|
+-----------+-----------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the combination of [regexp_replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#regexp_replace) and [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#split) api of function module

```
import pyspark.sql.types as t
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

l1 = [('anystring',),('a1234bc123',),('av1tb12h18',)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l1).toDF('col')
df.show()
+----------+
|       col|
+----------+
| anystring|
|a1234bc123|
|av1tb12h18|
+----------+
```

Now use replace matching regex and then split by ",". Here $1 refers to what is replaced value so it will be blank for matching regex.

```
e.g replace('anystring')
$0 = anystring
$1 = ""

dfl1 = df.withColumn('temp', f.split(f.regexp_replace("col", "[a-z]*([0-9]*)", "$1,"), ","))

dfl1.show()
+----------+---------------+
|       col|           temp|
+----------+---------------+
| anystring|         [, , ]|
|a1234bc123|[1234, 123, , ]|
|av1tb12h18|[1, 12, 18, , ]|
+----------+---------------+
```

**Spark <2.4**

Use UDF to replace empty values of array

```
def func_drop_from_array(arr):
    return [x for x in arr if x != '']

drop_from_array = f.udf(func_drop_from_array, t.ArrayType(t.StringType()))

dfl1.withColumn('final', drop_from_array('temp')).show()
+----------+---------------+-----------+
|       col|           temp|      final|
+----------+---------------+-----------+
| anystring|         [, , ]|         []|
|a1234bc123|[1234, 123, , ]|[1234, 123]|
|av1tb12h18|[1, 12, 18, , ]|[1, 12, 18]|
+----------+---------------+-----------+
```

**Spark >=2.4**

Use [array_remove](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#array_remove)

```
dfl1.withColumn('final', f.array_remove('temp','')).show()

+----------+---------------+-----------+
|       col|           temp|      final|
+----------+---------------+-----------+
| anystring|         [, , ]|         []|
|a1234bc123|[1234, 123, , ]|[1234, 123]|
|av1tb12h18|[1, 12, 18, , ]|[1, 12, 18]|
+----------+---------------+-----------+
```