# Remove period then email extension after '@' into new column to extract first and last name information

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, extract

I have a list of emails that are in the format firstname.lastname@email.com. I would like to create a new column with only the first and last name extracted from the email address.

I am using PySpark. This is an example of the desired output:

```py
data = [{"Email": "john.doe@email.com", "Role": "manager"},
{"Email": "jane.doe@email.com", "Role": "vp"}]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

type(df)

# original data set
+------------------+-------+
|Email             |Role   |
+------------------+-------+
|john.doe@email.com|manager|
|jane.doe@email.com|vp     |
+------------------|-------+

# what I want the output to look like
+------------------+-------+--------+
|Email             |Role   |Name    |
+------------------+-------+--------+
|john.doe@email.com|manager|john doe|
|jane.doe@email.com|vp     |jane doe|
+------------------|-------|--------+
```

How can I remove the period, replace it with a space, then drop everything after the @ into a new column to get the names like the example above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I extract all the instances of a regular expression pattern in PySpark dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57663331/how-can-i-extract-all-the-instances-of-a-regular-expression-pattern-in-pyspark-d)

Comment: @Chris Not 100% because I need to drop everything from the @ and after along with the split/replace on the period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will replace the `.` and `@...` with a space   which we'll have to trim from the end.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('Name', F.trim(F.regexp_replace('Email', '\.|@.*', ' '))).show()
# +------------------+-------+--------+
# |             Email|   Role|    Name|
# +------------------+-------+--------+
# |john.doe@email.com|manager|john doe|
# |jane.doe@email.com|     vp|jane doe|
# +------------------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's `.split` method for strings and a loop to add a "Name" field to each record in your list.

```py
for d in data:
    d["Name] = " ".join(d["Email"].split("@")[0].split("."))
```

In the above loop we split the "Email" field at the "@" character, creating a list of two elements, of which we take the first one, and then split that on the character ".", which gives us the first and last name.  Then we join them with a space (" ") in between.

Comment: Thank you. The logic makes sense but unfortunately, when I run this I get an invalid syntax error at "Email"

Comment: it was a typo. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex_extract` and `regex_replace`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn('Name', F.regexp_extract(
        F.regexp_replace('Email', '\.', ' '), 
        '(.*)@', 
        1)
     )
```

First, `regexp_replace('Email', '\.', ' ')` will replace `.` to space in `Email` column.

Then, `regexp_extract(..., '(.*)@', 1)` will extract the 1st capture group.

Regex explanation

```
(.*) => .* is any characters with any length. Wrap with () to make a capture group.
@ => match @ mark. 

(.*)@ => 1st Capture group will capture any characters before @.
```